# Will a 3-32 VDC input signal relay be damaged (or will work) with a 110 VAC input?

Tags: relay, temperature, solid-state-relay

I'm looking at getting a SSR-25DA relay ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0087ZTN08/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A1THAZDOWP300U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087ZTN08)) and using it with a temperature controller that has a 110 VAC output ([http://www.amazon.com/Lerway-All-Purpose-Temperature-Controller-Thermostat/dp/B008KVCPH2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1437090435&sr=8-1&keywords=temperature+controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008KVCPH2)).

I would prefer use the temperature controller alone to control a freezer, but the freezer has a 15 Amp draw, while the temperature controller is only rated for 10 Amps (I could not find an On/Off temperature controller for > 10 Amps). Is there any way I could get the temperature controller to trigger this 25 Amp relay, or do I need to look for a temperature controller with a lower DC output (or look for a mechanical relay that supports 110V signal)?

I would assume that this temperature controller has a built-in relay that is the limiting factor; do you think there is any way I could rewire the controller's relay signal to the larger relay I want to get?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solid state relay will certainly be destroyed if given 120 VAC on its control input.

However, looking closely at the pictures of the temperature controller, it appears to me that the outputs are isolated relay contacts.  If that is correct, then the contacts could be used to switch 12 V DC (or something acceptable to the SSR) to control the SSR.

Comment: Do you mean that the controller probably has 12 V contact points that I could use to trigger the 25 Amp relay?

Comment: No.  I mean that the controller has isolated contacts that you could use to switch any DC voltage you have handy to control the SSR.  The controller does not have a DC supply for you to use.

Comment: I see, so I would still need to provide a DC source in that case, thanks!